# javascript unable to find all a-tags on squarespace site

Tags: javascript, html

What could be the reason why the javascript function "languify" in the bottom of this page is not able to look up all the links in the topNav?

http://www.yggdrasildance.dk/

I'm writing all the links from the topNav to the console, but some are missing (for example 'about' and 'galleries').

I see that Squarespace has som additional javascript after my own. But even if I manually run the "languify" function once the page is completely loaded, the 'about' link remains unseen by the script.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var a_items = document.getElementById('topNav').getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < a_items.length; i++)
{
    console.log('inspecting link to: ' + a_items[i].getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Comment: please post the respective code along with the question..

Comment: works for me on Chrome (i.e. the loop iterates six times)

Comment: I think I've figured it out. The function removes the unwanted elements, thus updates the DOM and thereby invalidating the array indexes of a_items. Does it make sense?